# Can't find element in DOM using "next()" or "closest()"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have this DOM-tree:

```
<div class="field-group">
    <label for="timetracking_originalestimate">Original Estimate</label>
    <input class="text short-field" id="timetracking_originalestimate" name="timetracking_originalestimate" value="3d 5h" readonly="readonly" type="text">
    <span class="aui-form example">(eg. 3w 4d 12h)</span>
    <a class="help-lnk" href="/jira/secure/ShowTimeTrackingHelp.jspa?decorator=popup#TimeTracking" title="Get local help about Time Tracking" data-helplink="local">
        <span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-help"></span>
    </a>
    <div class="description">The original estimate of how much work is involved in resolving this issue.</div>
</div>
```

And I start with getting element by ID `#timetracking_originalestimate`.

Now I want to get the first element with class `description` following the pre-searched element with ID.

How can I get there? `next()` and `closest()` doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several ways to achieve this:

```
$('#timetracking_originalestimate').closest('.field-group').find('.description');
//Or
$("#timetracking_originalestimate").nextAll(".description");
//
$("#timetracking_originalestimate").siblings('.description');
```

Since `description` is a sibling of `#timetracking_originalestimate` I suggest the use the jQuery method **[`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** to target the element the use **[`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/)** to get the text of the element like:

```js
console.log( $("#timetracking_originalestimate").siblings('.description').text() );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="field-group">
  <label for="timetracking_originalestimate">Original Estimate</label>
  <input class="text short-field" id="timetracking_originalestimate" name="timetracking_originalestimate" value="3d 5h" readonly="readonly" type="text">
  <span class="aui-form example">(eg. 3w 4d 12h)</span>
  <a class="help-lnk" href="/jira/secure/ShowTimeTrackingHelp.jspa?decorator=popup#TimeTracking" title="Get local help about Time Tracking" data-helplink="local"><span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-help"></span></a>
  <div class="description">The original estimate of how much work is involved in resolving this issue.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to everybody! It's working, I think I understood the technique now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) to find next `.description`

```
$("#timetracking_originalestimate").nextAll(".description");
```

```js
$("#timetracking_originalestimate").nextAll(".description").css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field-group">
 <label for="timetracking_originalestimate">Original Estimate</label>
 <input class="text short-field" id="timetracking_originalestimate" name="timetracking_originalestimate" value="3d 5h" readonly="readonly" type="text">
 <span class="aui-form example">(eg. 3w 4d 12h)</span>
 <a class="help-lnk" href="/jira/secure/ShowTimeTrackingHelp.jspa?decorator=popup#TimeTracking" title="Get local help about Time Tracking" data-helplink="local"><span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-help"></span></a>
 <div class="description">The original estimate of how much work is involved in resolving this issue.</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use siblings() to find sibling elements in jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var html = $("#timetracking_originalestimate").siblings(".description").html();
  alert(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field-group">
   <label for="timetracking_originalestimate">Original Estimate</label>
   <input class="text short-field" id="timetracking_originalestimate" name="timetracking_originalestimate" value="3d 5h" readonly="readonly" type="text">
   <span class="aui-form example">(eg. 3w 4d 12h)</span>
   <a class="help-lnk" href="/jira/secure/ShowTimeTrackingHelp.jspa?decorator=popup#TimeTracking" title="Get local help about Time Tracking" data-helplink="local"><span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-help"></span></a>
   <div class="description">The original estimate of how much work is involved in resolving this issue.</div>
</div>
```